# SQL XML select where clause

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

I have something like this:

```
DECLARE @myDoc xml

Set @myDoc =
'<dati_indirizzi>
    <ind_generico>
        <id_indirizzo>1</id_indirizzo>
        <indirizzo>Via Magenta, 41/43</indirizzo>
        <nazione>
            <cod_uic>222</cod_uic>
            <nazione>CLIPPERTON</nazione>
        </nazione>
    </ind_generico>
    <ind_generico>
        <id_indirizzo>2</id_indirizzo>
        <indirizzo>Via Magenta, 41/43</indirizzo>
        <nazione>
            <cod_uic>999</cod_uic>
            <nazione>CLIPPERTON</nazione>
        </nazione>
    </ind_generico>
    <ind_generico>
        <id_indirizzo>3</id_indirizzo>
        <indirizzo>Via Magenta, 41/43</indirizzo>
    </ind_generico>
</dati_indirizzi>'

SELECT Mydoc.cod_uic.value('.', 'varchar(255)') as 'cod_uic'
FROM @myDoc.nodes('/dati_indirizzi/ind_generico/nazione/cod_uic') as Mydoc(cod_uic)
```

The result is:

### cod_uic

### 222

### 999

How can I get only the "cod_uic" where "id_indirizzo=2"? The result would be:

### cod_uic

### 999

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use predicate, i.e.:

```
@myDoc.nodes('/dati_indirizzi/ind_generico[id_indirizzo = 2]/nazione/cod_uic')
```

If you have predefined variable, e.g.: `declare @id int = 2`, then use `sql:variable()` function:

```
@myDoc.nodes('/dati_indirizzi/ind_generico[id_indirizzo = sql:variable("@id")]/nazione/cod_uic')
```

Comment: Hello, now it's works. But if I want something like this... @myDoc.nodes('/dati_indirizzi/ind_generico[id_indirizzo = '+ @id +']/nazione/cod_uic') I get that error: "The argument 1 of the XML data type method "nodes" must be a string literal". How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Update the xpath:

```
@myDoc.nodes('/dati_indirizzi/ind_generico[id_indirizzo=''2'']/nazione/cod_uic')
```